# Tensor with two indices

Tags: matrices, tensors

A tensor with two indices can be represented by a $3\times3$ matrix.

\begin{equation}
A= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33} \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

It make sense why is a $2$D matrix but why it's a $3\times3$ and not a $2\times2$, or $4\times4$?

Comment: I bet you find this in a physical book. The position of a point can be determined by a 3 dimension vector and thus tensor is 3 x 3

Comment: @Syuizen In case the tensor has only one index again the tensor will be 3 x 3?

Comment: No.  In n-dimensional space, a tensor ( precisely 2-order tensor) is n x n. All you need care is the dimension of the space you want to analyse

Comment: You *can* represent an order 2 tensor as a matrix, but let's remember what a tensor actually is: it's a multilinear mapping from an ordered list of vectors and covectors to the base field.  So the reason a type $(2,0)$ tensor would be representable by a $3\times 3$ matrix is because it *eats* two vectors in $3$-space.  So thinking of your vectors as column matrices, the tensor $T$ (represented by matrix $M$) acting those vectors $v,w\in \Bbb R^3$ would be calculable as the matrix product: $$v^TMw$$ If your tensor eats two vectors in $4$-dimensional space, then it'd be a $4\times 4$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

A rank-$n$ tensor is a linear map from a sequence of vector spaces to the reals(/complexes, but let's keep things simple). So it eats vectors, which are normally all in $d$ dimensions. Therefore a rank-$2$ tensor can be written as a two-index object $a_{ij}$, which acts linearly on $d$-dimensional vectors $v_i,w_j$ as
$$ \sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^d a_{ij} v_i w_j. $$
But this is the same as the summation from the matrix product $v^T A w$, so $A$ is a $d \times d$ matrix.

Comment: If I understand well it depends on the space you search. So the example I gave in the beginning means that they choose d=3 but a tensor with 2 indices can be represented by any $d \times d$ matrix. Am I right?

Comment: For any integer $d$, there are two-index tensors of dimension $d$ (which you can represent by $d \times d$ matrices). A given tensor has a specific number of dimensions of stuff it acts on (so if you have a tensor that acts in two dimensions, it only makes sense to represent it as a $2 \times 2$ matrix, for example).